# JavaScript: Cannot get .push() command to work as intended

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that loops through each item in an index and notes a certain item's index when encountered. In this function, when the item 'contraband' is encountered in the loop, the index is noted added, and the .push() command I've written is supposed to append each new index into an empty called 'contrabandIndexes'. However, the command or some other part of the code is not working as intended because when I run the function through the sample array, it returns with an empty array.

Where did I go wrong here?

```
function scan(freightItems) {
    let contrabandIndexes = [];
    freightItems.forEach(function(freightItem) {
        if (freightItem === 'contraband') {
            contrabandIndexes.push();
        }
    });
    return contrabandIndexes;
}

const indexes = scan(['dog', 'contraband', 'cat', 'zippers', 'contraband']);
console.log('Contraband Indexes: ' + indexes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forEach` Array method passes the index along with the element in question. So you can use that index value to append to your `contrabandIndexes` Array.

```js
function scan(freightItems) {
    const contrabandIndexes = [];
    freightItems.forEach(function(freightItem, idx) {
        if (freightItem === 'contraband') {
            contrabandIndexes.push(idx);
        }
    });
    return contrabandIndexes;
}

const indexes = scan(['dog', 'contraband', 'cat', 'zippers', 'contraband']);
console.log('Contraband Indexes: ' + indexes);
```

Also you don't need the `let contrabandIndexes = [];` outside of the function. At least not in this snippet.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GattMola this solution will NOT work for you. You can even try.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I didn't down vote any responses. I updated my response to include the input array and output (console.log).

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, I voted you down. This answer is correct. It returns an Array of the indexes where the value is `'contraband'`. Your answer just returns an array with `'contraband'` values in it.

Comment: @Jason Thanks Jason. I appreciate. As far as the question goes it never asked for indexes to be pushed. It so easy anyway. But Regardless. Thanks You :)

Answer (score -1):

After looking what others had to share, I think you should see this:

```js
function SecurityGuard(){
  this.band = [...arguments]; this.contraband = []; this.holds = []; this.keep = [];
  this.scan = array=>{
    const b = this.band, h = this.holds, c = this.contraband;
    array.forEach((v, i)=>{
      if(b.indexOf(v) === -1){
        h.push({[v]:i});
      }
      else{
        c.push({[v]:i});
      }
    });
    return this;
  }
  this.keepHolds = ()=>{
    const h = this.holds;
    h.forEach(o=>{
      for(let i in o){
        this.keep.push(i);
      }
    });
    h.splice(0);
    return this;
  }
  this.dumpContraband = ()=>{
    this.contraband.splice(0);
    return this;
  }
}
const sg = new SecurityGuard('gun', 'knife', 'noose');
sg.scan(['noose', 'gun', 'dog', 'gun', 'cat', 'zippers', 'knife', 'phone']);
console.log(sg.holds); console.log(sg.contraband); sg.keepHolds(); console.log(sg.keep);
```